# Regular expression for home address

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me with regular expression for checking home address please?

I came up with `/^([\w]([\.,]?)([\s]?)){1,60}$/`. It does the job except for addresses with `.,` on it.

Eg: `Cabalan Rd.,`

Is there any way that it could include `.`, `,` and/or both `.,`?

Comment: There's exactly **zero** chance you can correctly "check" the incredible variety of home addresses that people have. All you can do is make sure you have *something* and make sure the user has a chance to check it's correct.

Comment: As well as having different areas, different countries have different formats for their addresses. Also, some countries use non-ASCII characters for their addresses, failing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can improve your expression a bit more:

```
/^(?:\w+\.?,?\s?){1,60}$/
```

- `\w+`: Matches one or more word characters.
- `\.?,?`: Tries to match a single `.`, `,` or `.,` or nothing at all.
- `\s?`: An optional space.
- `(?: ... ){1,60}`: Match the previous items between `1` and `60` times.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^([\w]([\.,]*)([\s]?)){1,60}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/I0B3lPbJ0xSmZXZC)

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` to recount all acceptable combinations:

```
/^([\w](\.|,|\.,)([\s]?)){1,60}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your regex to:

```
/^([\w.,\s]){1,60}$/
```

But have to say that validating address with regex is not such a great idea.

Comment: Yes it will and I will enhance it after seeing all the rules of this regex from OP.